# Browse an array of structs

Tags: c, memory-management, segmentation-fault

I have an array of structs, each of which describes what I would call a signal. I declared my struct this way :

```
 /* Structure for keywords */
 struct varStruct
 {
    char* varName;
    int varOccurence;
 } signals[MAX_SIGNALS];
```

I'm working in a loop which analyze a file and dynamically find the signal declarations, called **newArrayName** in my case. What I would like to do, is to add the read signal to the array ONLY IF it's not already contained. Otherwise, I should increment the varOccurence variable.

Here is my code, but I have a segmentation fault (so no further information)...

```
    // We are in the loop that get the signals sequentially
    char* newArrayName = TheValueOfTheReadSignal.

    int i;
    // We browse all the array...
    for(i=0; i < MAX_SIGNALS; i++)
    {
        // If a signal already has the name of the currently-read signal, we inc its occurence
        if(strcmp(signals[i].varName, newArrayName) == 0)
        {
            signals[i].varOccurence++;
        }
        // Otherwise, we add a new signal with the read-name and an occurence corresponding to the value of a static variable that's incremented after each signal-reading.
        else
        {
            signals[index_Array].varName = newArrayName;
            signals[index_Array].varOccurence = index_Array;

        }
    }
     // We increment index_Array, which is a static int variable
       index_Array ++;
    // End of the loop that gets the signals
```

Which leads to a segmentation fault. I'm not very good in C language, I would even say I am very bad at it. My guess here is that the signal array has not been initialized, so signal[i] doesn't have any sense for him, but I don't know how to initialize an array of structs. Maybe it's another reason, I don't know.

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Are you sure that `index_Array` isn't bigger than `MAX_SIGNALS`?

Comment: How do you get `TheValueOfTheReadSignal`?

Comment: Can you run it through a debugger to see on which line it crashes?

Comment: @Electro : it's a function, but it has many parameters and it was (I think), irrelevant to write it. It does work, I can printf the name of the current signal.

Comment: Are you copying the string when you read it in? Do you initialize the array at startup? Is `varName` ever `NULL`?

Comment: Returns `TheValueOfTheReadSignal` an malloced `char` pointer? Otherwise the won't be anything to compare.

Comment: @Electro : No, I did not initialize my array. And yes, I just printed signal[i].varName in my for-loop, and it's NULL everywhere. The problem is that I don't have access to the main() method here, so I should be able to initialize it when I declare it, which I don't know how.

Comment: There is no point in initializing the array. Don't loop over all the elements from 0 to MAX_SIGNALS-1. Loop only from 0 to index_Array-1. This means, you never read the invalid, uninitialized pointers at all, and also means you finish your loop faster. This is what I have explained in my answer as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While you have no entries in recorded `signals`, or when `i` is larger than the number of recorded entries minus one,, the `strcmp(signals[i].varName, newArrayName)` tries to dereference the invalid (uninitialised or `NULL`) pointer `signals[i].varName`.

Beyond that, as soon as `index_Array` becomes as large as `MAX_SIGNALS` (or larger),

```
// We browse all the array...
for(i=0; i < MAX_SIGNALS; i++)
{
    // If a signal already has the name of the currently-read signal, we inc its occurence
    if(strcmp(signals[i].varName, newArrayName) == 0)
    {
        signals[i].varOccurence++;
    }
    // Otherwise, we add a new signal with the read-name and an occurence corresponding to the value of a static variable that's incremented after each signal-reading.
    else
    {
        signals[index_Array].varName = newArrayName;
        signals[index_Array].varOccurence = index_Array;

    }
}
 // We increment index_Array, which is a static int variable
   index_Array ++;
```

you write past the end of the array, which is undefined behaviour and will likely cause memory corruption and/or a segmentation fault - directly, or as a consequence of the memory corruption.

In your loop, you write to `signals[index_Array]` every time you find a signal with a different name, and you increment `index_Array` each time after the loop is run, regardless of whether you already have some signal with that name or not. You should check whether you already have recorded the signal, and only if not write the new entry and increment `index_Array`:

```
// Check for newArrayName == NULL and exit or otherwise handle the situation if it is
// We browse all the array...
for(i=0; i < index_Array && i < MAX_SIGNALS; i++)
{
    // If a signal already has the name of the currently-read signal, we inc its occurence
    if(signals[i].varName != NULL && strcmp(signals[i].varName, newArrayName) == 0)
    {
        signals[i].varOccurence++;
        break; // we already have that signal, can stop looping
    }
}
// Check if i == MAX_SIGNALS
// if it is, we have no more space in the array,
// that needs handling
if (i == index_Array && index_Array < MAX_SIGNALS) {
    // We haven't had that signal before, record it
    signals[index_Array].varName = newArrayName;
    signals[index_Array].varOccurence = index_Array;
    // And increment index_Array, which is a static int variable
    index_Array ++;
}
```

Comment: I would appreciate an explanation of the downvote, even if it's just a guess of the reason. Any ideas anyone?

Comment: None - I also suffered from anon downvote without explanation.

Comment: Someone downvoted every single posts here. I voted up, since you all helped me. But yeah, I hope the downvoter will explain...

Comment: @DanielFischer, a problem with your answer is that there is no protection to `varName` being `NULL` when passing to `strcmp()`, doubt that was reason you were downvoted though as I have that protection but still received downvote.

Comment: Unexplained downvotes suck. I didn't realize I had one until I saw NNzz's comment.

Comment: @hmjd Yes, right. That shouldn't happen with `0 <= i < index_Array`, since the array should be filled sequentially with valid structs, but it's better to check for `NULL`. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: I don't understand the first loop : for(i=0; i < index_Array && i < MAX_SIGNALS; i++). Why don't we browse all the array ?

Comment: @NNzz Since `index_Array` is the position where a new signal was written to, I conjectured that the positions 0 to `index_Array-1` were those where a signal was already noted, and of course you'd only check the array as far as it is already filled. If that conjecture is wrong, a different loop bound would be appropriate. But still, you'd only want the loop to go as far as the array is filled.

Comment: Oh right, I get it. Seems pretty logical :). I will validate your answer as definitive, even if the attended behaviour is still not reached (I have a signal that's repeated 10 times, and it's just incremented till 3, and then i =/= index_Array, which I don't know why). Thanks for your help anyways :)

Comment: @NNzz You get 10 times the same signal, but its occurrence count is only incremented to 3? What happens the other times? Is a new entry created for each occurrence? Is it possible that the signal name `newArrayName` might sometimes contain trailing whitespace (newlines, perhaps)? Try some printf-debugging, `printf(">%s<\n",newArrayName);` to see whitespace if there is any.

Comment: The problems seems to be that (with this code), the occurence of the first signal will be the value of index_array (0), the occurence of the second signal will be 1, the occurence of the third signal will be 2, the occurence of the fourth signal (the one that's repeated) will be 3. So basically, there is a problem when I add a signal for the first time. I'll check what I did wrong... Because here, the value of the occurence is basically the value of index_Array. Nothing else. I'll edit my post. Or maybe it's because I don't put my printf() function at the right place. Where shall I put it ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10842/discussion-between-daniel-fischer-and-nnzz)

Answer (score 2):

A problem is that on first iteration all of the `varName` members will be either `NULL` or an uninitialised pointer (depending on where `signals` is declared). Ensure they are initialised to `NULL`:

```
struct varStruct
{
    char* varName;
    int varOccurence;
} signals[MAX_SIGNALS] = { {0} };
```

And check if it is `NULL` before passing to `strcmp()`:

```
if(signals[i].varName && strcmp(signals[i].varName, newArrayName) == 0)
```

If `varName` is NULL it would indicate that no further elements have been populated and you could populate it and break from the loop.

Additionally ensure:

- That the value assigned to the `varName` is dynamically allocated (using `malloc()` for example) and lives for as long is required, remembering to `free()` `varName` when no longer required.
- `index_Array` is less than `MAX_SIGNALS` before populating an element of `signals`.

Comment: That makes sense, it solved my error. And yes, I will ensure that I malloc varName and that index_Array < MAX_SIGNALS.

Answer (score 2):

1. You are creating a 'new' entry within the search loop itself. That would create a new entry right away, almost every time. You should be creating the new entry only after *all* the existing entries don't match; i.e. after you are done with the loop.
2. You should not be looping till `MAX_SIGNALS` because in the beginning, most of your array is empty. Only the first `index_Array` elements are real. This also rids you of initializing your struct with NULL pointers, and checking for them, Because you won't loop over uninitialized entries anyway.
3. You are incrementing `index_Array` blindly. Only increment when you *really* add an entry.

Some changes:

```
// We are in the loop that get the signals sequentially
char* newArrayName = TheValueOfTheReadSignal.

int found_entry;
found_entry = FALSE; /* A flag that remembers if the entry has been found.  */

for(i=0; i < index_Array; i++)
{
    if(strcmp(signals[i].varName, newArrayName) == 0)
    {
        signals[i].varOccurence++;
        found_entry = TRUE;
        break;
    }
}
if (!found_entry)
{
    signals[index_Array].varName = newArrayName;
    signals[index_Array].varOccurence = index_Array++;
}
```